# No data-frame returned with get_mon_arrivals() for Simmer

Tags: r

A simulation model I created with Simmer returns a meaningful data-frame with get_mon_attributes(), however only a data-frame with 2 rows with get_mon_arrivals(). (My original code only returns a data-frame with no rows at this point). I use both data-frames to create a new data-frame to display queue and activity durations (of which there are three each) as well as throughput time for each arrival, which is then further analysed for output with Shiny (not shown in reproducible example below).

A previous version of this code worked well without issues, in spite of a more complex calculation of activity times.

I kept the reproducible example as small as possible - much of it is data. I realize it is quite large, not sure how to reduce it further, without changing it too much with regards to the original code.

I didn't find a similar problem on google or stackoverflow.com.

```
library(simmer)
library(dplyr)

arrivalsAtHatchV <- c(33.05, 59.65, 133.15, 187.683333333333, 
190.916666666667, 191.316666666667, 
                      191.733333333333, 192.2, 225.283333333333, 226.15, 
232.483333333333, 
                      250.983333333333, 294.616666666667, 295.05, 
342.083333333333, 
                      370.283333333333, 376.35, 381.816666666667, 
392.716666666667, 
                      393.866666666667, 398.666666666667, 
399.116666666667, 400.8, 
                      415.85, 429.65, 433.35, 436.466666666667, 
437.883333333333, 439, 
                      440.2, 440.633333333333, 441.216666666667, 
443.066666666667, 
                      457.25, 461.933333333333, 479.783333333333, 
523.083333333333, 
                      524.45)

arrivalsFromWardV <- c(18.3666666666667, 18.3666666666667, 46.15, 
72.4333333333333, 
                       72.45, 72.45, 72.4666666666667, 76.75, 80.6, 
88.3833333333333, 
                       99, 100.383333333333, 103.366666666667, 117.6, 
117.683333333333, 
                       125.466666666667, 136.633333333333, 
136.633333333333, 150.033333333333, 
                       156.6, 156.6, 158.833333333333, 158.833333333333, 
158.833333333333, 
                       158.85, 161.283333333333, 171.366666666667, 
171.366666666667, 
                       175.283333333333, 177.733333333333, 180.85, 
193.366666666667, 
                       193.383333333333, 208.266666666667, 
208.683333333333, 209.166666666667, 
                       209.266666666667, 209.366666666667, 218.55, 
220.3, 232.733333333333, 
                       235.683333333333, 237.95, 237.95, 
240.383333333333, 254.083333333333, 
                       254.75, 262.066666666667, 263.933333333333, 
263.95, 275.05, 282.25, 
                       291.45, 293.8, 309.25, 324.633333333333, 
335.816666666667, 341, 
                       342.316666666667, 343.15, 360.7, 364.5, 
388.383333333333, 388.383333333333, 
                       396.183333333333, 402.016666666667, 
414.833333333333, 434.716666666667, 
                       434.716666666667, 449.116666666667, 
453.266666666667, 461.8, 
                       469.75, 471.9, 476.116666666667, 476.2, 
478.683333333333, 480.033333333333, 
                       494.266666666667, 495.983333333333, 507.25)

defaultShiftMatrix <- structure(c(0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 1, 
                                  2, 4, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("disp. pharmacist", 

"ward pharmacist", "pharm. tech.", "checking tech."), c("8-9 a.m.", 

"9-11 a.m.", "11 a.m.-1 p.m.", "1-3 p.m.", "3-5 p.m.", "5-6:30 p.m."

)))

outPatDurForChosenDate <- structure(list(RxID = c(108323, 108326, 
108340, 108356, 108357, 
                                                  108358, 108359, 108360, 108370, 108371, 108372, 108381, 108391, 
                                              108392, 108399, 108404, 108405, 108407, 108410, 108411, 108414, 
                                              108415, 108416, 108420, 108421, 108422, 108425, 108426, 108427, 
                                              108428, 108429, 108431, 108432, 108436, 108438, 108447, 108455, 
                                              108456), verifActivity = c(65, 1046, 1884, 82, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 
                                                                         663, 103, 4, 6, 5, 125, 9, 3, 13, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 29, 5, 202, 
                                                                         7, 3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 5, 2, 132, 5), dispActivity = c(602, 8, 
                                                                                                                              702, 1032, 399, 172, 250, 301, 745, 303, 59, 4, 1278, 173, 728, 
                                                                                                                              102, 356, 112, 4, 561, 1165, 383, 560, 433, 568, 604, 630, 378, 
                                                                                                                              486, 3, 305, 378, 822, 257, 674, 1656, 413, 2), finCheckActivity = c(284, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   162, 305, 3, 290, 163, 386, 282, 90, 56, 28, 72, 202, 67, 45, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   163, 67, 59, 48, 3, 54, 2, 1, 3, 4, 263, 92, 7, 56, 2, 4, 2332, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   718, 77, 7, 2, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame")

inPatDurForChosenDate <- structure(list(RxID = c(108318, 108319, 108324, 108327, 108328, 
                                             108329, 108330, 108331, 108332, 108333, 108334, 108335, 108336, 
                                             108337, 108338, 108339, 108341, 108342, 108343, 108344, 108345, 
                                             108346, 108347, 108348, 108349, 108350, 108351, 108352, 108353, 
                                             108354, 108355, 108361, 108362, 108363, 108364, 108365, 108366, 
                                             108367, 108368, 108369, 108373, 108374, 108375, 108376, 108377, 
                                             108382, 108383, 108384, 108385, 108386, 108387, 108388, 108389, 
                                             108390, 108394, 108396, 108397, 108398, 108400, 108401, 108402, 
                                             108403, 108408, 108409, 108413, 108417, 108419, 108423, 108424, 
                                             108434, 108435, 108437, 108440, 108441, 108443, 108444, 108446, 
                                             108448, 108450, 108451, 108454), verifActivity = c(514, 224, 
                                                                                                205, 1370, 9, 4751, 390, 5, 1057, 3699, 240, 30, 46147, 796, 
                                                                                                753, 1020, 39, 713, 703, 401, 13517, 128, 507, 6391, 160, 6, 
                                                                                                136, 293, 596, 196, 287, 863, 1770, 4, 548, 4, 462, 99, 118, 
                                                                                                217, 7031, 10, 4504, 599, 44, 143, 127, 1239, 164, 94, 926, 77, 
                                                                                                172, 4, 982, 760, 456, 44, 164, 3, 466, 2672, 710, 635, 445, 
                                                                                                820, 2575, 8, 7, 92, 1283, 36, 4, 13, 7, 51, 131, 3, 15, 2, 4
                                             ), dispActivity = c(3, 1202, 4482, 100, 2611, 9600, 667, 1169, 
                                                                 596, 1124, 3, 8, 1673, 673, 977, 145, 592, 892, 300, 4004, 435, 
                                                                 728, 969, 1695, 1308, 8, 382, 470, 880, 366, 589, 1113, 1456, 
                                                                 606, 3256, 2135, 964, 145, 499, 3690, 4473, 622, 399, 878, 1687, 
                                                                 547, 1610, 3698, 966, 745, 127, 72, 658, 404, 15, 4103, 5827, 
                                                                 1175, 508, 127, 792, 2723, 33411, 617, 5037, 855, 607, 1093, 
                                                                 169, 3608, 925, 78, 1151, 53, 733, 1755, 579, 2014, 7953, 273, 
                                                                 999), finCheckActivity = c(422, 4, 3, 8, 273, 2257, 149, 579, 
                                                                                            247, 316, 783, 2, 1, 175, 1978, 67, 545, 209, 4, 635, 4, 178, 
                                                                                            424, 4, 2, 3, 2, 328, 163, 71, 116, 598, 1, 2, 1430, 150, 343, 
                                                                                            22, 304, 758, 36, 201, 3, 1, 324, 157, 108, 874, 108, 94, 4, 
                                                                                            3, 4, 31, 4, 3, 863, 6, 1, 118, 3, 64, 806, 4, 4, 215, 3, 131, 
                                                                                            504, 1, 63, 3, 4, 278, 116, 5, 76, 1, 382, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                             -81L), class = "data.frame")

#The simulation model below is a function that requires a shift pattern for
#four roles, a vector outlining arrivals at the hatch and a vector outlining arrivals
#from the ward, both over 1 working day, i.e. the simulator
#runs over 1 working day. It returns a data-frame of the arrivals and one for
#their attributes:
simulationResults <- function(shiftMatrix, arrivalsAtHatchVect, 
                          arrivalsFromWardVect, outPatDurs, inPatDurs, repeatNumber){
  #outPatDurs is a data-frame containing the activity durations for outpatients
  #for a chosen date
  #inPatDurs is a the equivalent data-frame for inpatient wards

  arrivalsAtHatchV <- arrivalsAtHatchVect
  arrivalsFromWardV <- arrivalsFromWardVect

  outpatientDurations <- outPatDurs
  inpatientDurations <- inPatDurs

  #Data input of average durations of main activities per arrival
  #and duration of run.I will assume that time-units are minutes.
  runDuration <- 630 #630 min. would be 10.5 hours, e.g. from 8:00 a.m. to 6:30 p.m.
  arrivalFromHatch <- "hatch" #The name used for arrivals at the hatch in the model.
  arrivalFromWard <- "wards" #The name used for arrivals from the wards in the model.

  #Schedules (i.e. shifts for resources):
  shiftTimes <- c(0, 60, 180, 300, 420, 540) # this corresponds to 8 a.m., 
  #9 a.m., 11 a.m., 1 p.m., 3 p.m., and 5 p.m. - this is when number of resources
  #change
  disp.pharmacist.sched <- schedule(shiftTimes,
                                shiftMatrix["disp. pharmacist",], period = 630)
  ward.pharmacist.sched <- schedule(shiftTimes,
                                shiftMatrix["ward pharmacist",], period = 630)
  pharm.tech.sched <- schedule(shiftTimes,
                           shiftMatrix["pharm. tech.",], period = 630)
  fin.check.sched <- schedule(shiftTimes,
                          shiftMatrix["checking tech.",], period = 630)

  arrivalDataFrame <- NULL

  for (counter in (1:repeatNumber)){

    #since I want to keep the activity durations of a particular prescription
    #together, I will just create a vector of randomly selected RxIDs from 
    #the outpatient or inpatient prescription data for the chosen day - 
    #these prescription numbers will be used to access the activity data
    #later prescription by prescription
    outpatientRxIDs <- sample(x = outpatientDurations %>% pull(RxID), 
                          size = outpatientDurations %>% nrow(), 
                          replace = F)
    inpatientRxIDs <- sample(x = inpatientDurations %>% pull(RxID), 
                         size = inpatientDurations %>% nrow(), 
                         replace = F)

    ##############################################################
    #Defining Simmer environment:
    pharmacy <- simmer("Dispensing Process")

    #Defining trajectory with 2 activities, the distribution of their durations
    #and their required resources:
    dispProcess <- trajectory("dispensing & final checking") %>% 
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){5}) %>% # 5 ... waiting for dispensing
  seize("dispenser", 1) %>%
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){6}) %>% # 6 ... start of dispensing
  timeout(function() {durationCalculator(get_name(pharmacy),

get_attribute(pharmacy,"progress"),
                                         outpatientRxIDs,
                                         inpatientRxIDs,
                                         outpatientDurations,
                                         inpatientDurations)}) %>% #********
  release("dispenser", 1) %>%
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){7}) %>% # 7 ... waiting for final checking
  simmer::select(resources = c("final checker","disp_pharmacist"), policy = 'shortest-queue') %>%
  seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){8}) %>% # 8 ... start of final checking
  timeout(function() {durationCalculator(get_name(pharmacy),

get_attribute(pharmacy,"progress"),
                                         outpatientRxIDs,
                                         inpatientRxIDs,
                                         outpatientDurations,
                                         inpatientDurations)}) %>% #********
  release_selected(amount = 1) %>%
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){9}) # 9 ... finish of final checking and process 

    #Part of the trajectory that covers the verifying of prescriptions from the ward:
    verifyingOnWards <- trajectory("verifying on wards") %>%
  #Attribute keeping track of progress of Rx in process:
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){1}) %>% # 1 ... waiting for verifying 
  seize("ward pharmacist", 1) %>%   
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){2}) %>% # 2 ... start of verifying
  timeout(function() {durationCalculator(get_name(pharmacy),
                                         get_attribute(pharmacy,"progress"),
                                         outpatientRxIDs,
                                         inpatientRxIDs,
                                         outpatientDurations,
                                         inpatientDurations)}) %>%
  release("ward pharmacist", 1)

    #Part of the trajectory that covers the verifying of prescriptions from the hatch (mainly
    #outpatient Rxs):
    verifyingOutpatients <- trajectory("verifying in dispensary") %>%
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){1}) %>% # 1 ... waiting for verifying 
  seize("disp_pharmacist", 1) %>%   
  set_attribute(keys = "progress", values = function(){2}) %>% # 2 ... start of verifying
  timeout(function() {durationCalculator(get_name(pharmacy),
                                         get_attribute(pharmacy,"progress"),
                                         outpatientRxIDs,
                                         inpatientRxIDs,
                                         outpatientDurations,
                                         inpatientDurations)}) %>%
  release("disp_pharmacist", 1)

    prescriptFromWard <- join(verifyingOnWards, dispProcess)
    prescriptFromHatch <- join(verifyingOutpatients, dispProcess)

    #Defining number of resources (i.e. staff) available:
pharmacy %>% 
  add_resource("disp_pharmacist", disp.pharmacist.sched) %>% 
  add_resource("ward pharmacist", ward.pharmacist.sched) %>% 
  add_resource("dispenser", pharm.tech.sched) %>% 
  add_resource("final checker", fin.check.sched) %>% 
  add_generator(arrivalFromHatch, prescriptFromHatch, at(arrivalsAtHatchV), mon = 2) %>%
  add_generator(arrivalFromWard, prescriptFromWard, at(arrivalsFromWardV), mon = 2)

    #Defining length of simulation run:
    pharmacy %>% run(until = runDuration)

    #Output of data to data-frame:
    arrivals.df <- pharmacy %>% get_mon_arrivals() %>% .[order(.$start_time),] 
    attributes.df <- pharmacy %>% get_mon_attributes() %>% .[order(.$time),]

    arrivalDataFrame <- arrivalDataFrame %>%
  rbind(arrivals.df %>% cbind(trial = counter))

  }

  return(arrivalDataFrame)
}


#This function returns a duration dependend on attributes in the trajectory below; 
durationCalculator <- function(arrivName, activity, outpatRxIDs, 
                           inpatRxIDs, outpatDurs, inpatDurs){
  #arrivName is the name of the arrival, e.g. "wards11", or "hatch5" - 
  #the last digits are to count the arrivals
  #activity is an integer from 1 to 9
  #depending on these two parameters an activity duration is picked from a
  #data-frame, i.e. outpatientDurations or inpatientDurations

  kounter <- substr(arrivName, start =  6, stop = nchar(arrivName)) %>% #both arrival names have 5 letters
as.integer() %>% "+" (1) #this is to extract the number of the arrival 
  currActivity <- switch(activity %>% as.character(), "2" ="verifActivity", 
                     "6" = "dispActivity", "8" = "finCheckActivity")
  if (grepl("hatch",arrivName)){ #this expression would be true for an inpatient Rx
        r <- outpatDurs[
      outpatDurs$RxID == outpatRxIDs[kounter],
  currActivity]
      }else{
        r <- inpatDurs[
  inpatDurs$RxID == inpatRxIDs[kounter],
  currActivity]
      }

      return(r)
    }

simulationResults(defaultShiftMatrix, arrivalsAtHatchV, arrivalsFromWardV, 
              outPatDurForChosenDate, inPatDurForChosenDate, 1) %>% #the last digit is the number of 
  print()
```

I would have expected the Simmer simulation to take account of all arrivals as per arrivalsAtHatchV and arrivalsFromWardV. This does not happen, however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the error - the data I fed the simulator is in seconds, should have been in minutes for the simulator model :-(

Answer (score 0):

See comment above. Need to watch what I feed my functions in the future.